# where is "Add service" button for add packagist in github

Tags: github, composer-php

I prepare composer package  and add it with packagist, but I'm in trouble in the settings.

And I can not find the "Add service" button in the github

and i run  "composer require gheibipour/composer-add-pakage"

Thank you for helping me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mz7Qf.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORWVy.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from home page of [packagist](https://packagist.org/) please read Publishing Packages and goes step by step to add your package from github to composer .

> Add services is deprecated in github